# How to syndicate Blogger blog to Facebook?

Tags: facebook, blog, blogger

How do I publish all posts from a Blogger blog to Facebook?
I know that for Wordpress there is a plugin for that, but I didn't find any way to do this on Blogger.

Answer (score 1):

Run a search for "[RSS](http://www.facebook.com/search.php?q=rss&init=quick&type=apps)" in the Apps section of Facebook.

You'll come across some such as [RSS Graffiti](http://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti/), [Simple RSS Tab](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=129498247112239), etc.

If you install them on your profile you should be able to hook them up to the RSS feed of your blog and have it republished or syndicated on your wall.

Answer (score 0):

1. On Facebook, click on 'More' Apps, then on 'Notes' (in the left column)
2. Then click on 'My Notes'
3. Click on 'Import Settings' (in the left column). It should take you to [this](http://www.facebook.com/editnotes.php) page
4. Enter your blog url, click the checkbox
   [image: blog parameters]
5. Your blog posts will now be posted as Notes

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to share your blogs automatically in Facebook, Twitter and Linked in by using http://twitterfeed.com. You need to specify the URL or the RSS feed. Every half hour or whatever time you specify, twitterfeed updates new blogs automatically.